# jquery mobile - Dynamically created items are not removed on page back & forth

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have two pages inside a single html:

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="select">
    <h2>Please choose a date and group:</h2>

    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
    <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="LoadRegister()"/>
</div> <!-- End of select page -->


<div data-role="page" id="mainregister" data-external-page="true">      
    <div data-role="content" id="subregister">

        <table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive" id="tblregister">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id= "tblregisterbody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveRegister()"/>

</div>
```

The user picks the date from the `select` page and on hitting the button the following is called:

```
    function LoadRegister(){

    var today = new Date(picker.get());

    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", '#mainregister', {
        transition: 'flip'
    });

    GetRegister(today, 2);
}
```

The `GetRegister()` function loads data and creates some elements dynamically (mostly radio buttons inside a fieldset).

This all works great. However, if the user goes back to the `select` page to choose a different date, then hits the button again the page is incorrect - I can see that the old fieldsets that were created on the first load are still there.

How can I get remove these dynamically created items (effectively reload `mainregister` page as per the HTML and start again)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but worked for me:

```
$('#tblregisterbody').empty();
```

I simply clear the element which contains the dynamically generated elements within the `LoadRegister` function before doing the page change.

```
function LoadRegister(){

var today = new Date(picker.get());
$('#tblregisterbody').empty(); // This clears the table with the dynamic elements
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", '#mainregister', {
    transition: 'flip'
});

GetRegister(today, 2);
```

}